# Nuxt v-bind not working with NuxtUI icons and util file

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt 3 App with NuxtUI as UI Framework.
To reuse icons and to avoid typos I create a file `/utils/Icon.ts` that looks like this:

```js
export enum IconSet {
  HeroIcons = 'heroicons'
}

export class Icon {
   readonly set: IconSet
   readonly name: string

   constructor(set: IconSet, name: string) {
     this.set = set
     this.name = name
   }

   toString(): string {
     return `i-${this.set}-${this.name}`
   }

   static preConfigured = {
     home: new Icon(IconSet.HeroIcons, 'home').toString(),
     user: new Icon(IconSet.HeroIcons, 'user').toString(),
     lock_open: new Icon(IconSet.HeroIcons, 'lock-open').toString(),
     lock_closed: new Icon(IconSet.HeroIcons, 'lock-closed').toString(),
     gear: new Icon(IconSet.HeroIcons, 'cog-6-tooth').toString(),
   }
}
```

The preConfigured Icons are the ones im trying to use like this:

```js
<template>
  <UButton :ui="ui" :icon="Icon.preConfigured.user" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Icon } from '#imports';

defineProps({
  ui: Object
})
console.log(Icon.preConfigured)
</script>
```

But for some reason this isn't working.
The logged output is as expected:

```js
{
  home: 'i-heroicons-home',
  user: 'i-heroicons-user',
  lock_open: 'i-heroicons-lock-open',
  lock_closed: 'i-heroicons-lock-closed',
  gear: 'i-heroicons-cog-6-tooth'
}
```

I also tested every icon name, it's working if I use them like this:

```js
<template>
  <UButton :ui="ui" :icon="icon" />
  <UButton :ui="ui" icon="i-heroicons-user" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  ui: Object
})
const icon = 'i-heroicons-user'
</script>
```

When expecting the icon element in the browser, it always looks like this, no matter if the icon is there or not:

```html
<span class="i-heroicons-user flex-shrink-0 h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

It gets even weirder, because when I'm testing and switching back from an working example to my `Icon` class, the icon still is there, but only until I restart the dev server.
Does anyone know, what might cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses the [egoist/tailwindcss-icons](https://github.com/egoist/tailwindcss-icons) which based on Tailwind engine that bundles only the static icons declared in your code as explained [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names). So you need to hardcode them statically then get access them using a literal object or an array. You can use [vscode-iconify](https://github.com/antfu/vscode-iconify) extension that shows valid icons directly in the editor.